# Latte: Didn't find overgiven parameter

Tags: php, latte

I try to use the latte template engine.
I register the Engine and try to render a template with parameters:

```
$latte = new Latte\Engine;

$events = new Event((new Config())->connectDB());
$result = $events->getAll();

$latte->render('templates/events.latte', $result);
```

This is the part from the template file:

```
{layout 'base.latte'}

{block title}Veranstaltungs&uuml;bersicht{/block}

{block content}
  {foreach $result as $row}
....
```

When I try this, I get this eror:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: result in ...../vendor/latte/latte/src/Latte/Engine.php(179) : eval()'d code on line 60
```

But when I make a var_dump($result) directly before $latte I get this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(8) { ["address"]=> string(38) "Street" ["date"]=> string(10) "2015-05-15" ["desc"]=> string(20) "sadfasdfasdfasdfasdf" ["event_participant"]=> int(25) ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(12) "Church" ["reservation_date"]=> string(10) "2015-05-10" ["church_id"]=> int(1) } }
```

So I don get it.
Why can latte not find the $result variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current code, you pass no "name" for that `$result` array to the template, only the array itself. Thus, your rendering engine does not know the name of that variable, but only the content.

To make this work, change the `render` call to:

```
$latte->render('templates/events.latte', ['result' => $result]);
```